# valueChangeListener behaviour when autoSubmit="true" immediate="true"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, trinidad, valuechangelistener, immediate-attribute

I am using Trinidad. For radio buttons and drop down I am using `valueChangeListener` with `autoSubmit="true"` to update a part of the page. But it displays the validations if any, so I used `immediate="true"` to bypass the validations. It worked but `valueChangeListener` doesn't work when I have the drop down inside a loop when I used iterator.

Can anyone explain the behaviour of `valueChangeListener` with `autoSubmit` and `immediate`?

Comment: The `autoSubmit="true"` doesn't exist in the standard JSF component set. You seem to be talking about the 3rd party component library Trinidad (as confirmed by your previous question). In the future, please explicitly mention and tag that as such. Otherwise your question is very confusing to ones who  and aren't familiar with Trinidad and assume that you're using the standard JSF component set.

Comment: sorry will keep that in mind for future posts. I really like all your articles with lots of good information .Thanks BaluC